# Talk to web service without SoapClient in php?

Tags: php, soap-client

I'm severely annoyed with many shared hosting providers not enabling SoapClient support on their hosting environments. Usualy, after a lot of begging and growling they enable it for me, but sometimes they just won't budge.

So, is it possible to consume web service on php without using SoapClient class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use [NuSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/) as a drop-in, or build custom XML. There may be other packages, afaik NuSOAP is the most well known.